# Algorithm to match finger prints in delphi

Tags: algorithm, delphi, fingerprint

Is there any library in delphi that i can use to match a database of finger prints with the ones scanned? I have browsed the net for some algos, but most of them were in pseudo code. I don't know much of the math and imaging analysis.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

FingerPrint SDK seems to have a DLL for Delphi. Supports lots of readers.
See here http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/en-us/fingerprint_sdk

Edit :
BTW, you don't need to be an expert on fingerprint analysis algorithms to use such a library.
Just learn how to use it and how to couple your fingerprint databases.